# PYTHON Runge Kutta 4 algorithm for 2nd order ODE

Tags: runge-kutta-methods, python

I have to solve the ODE system with RK4, the problem is, my Python gives small errors each step, and on long interval the result becomes incorrect.

Here is my Phyton code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myu=398600.4418E+9
J2=1.08262668E-3
req=6378137

t0=86400*2.3567000000000000E+04
tN= 86400*2.3567250000000000E+04


def f(t, y):
    r = (y[0]**2 + y[1]**2 + y[2]**2)**0.5
    r2=r**2
    r3=r**3

    w=1+1.5*J2*(req*req/r2)*(1-5*y[2]*y[2]/r2)

    return np.array([
        y[3],
        y[4],
        y[5],
        -myu*y[0]*w/r3,
        -myu*y[1]*w/r3,
        -myu*y[2]*w/r3,
    ])

def rk4(f, h, y0, t0):
    k1 = f(t0, y0)
    k2 = f(t0 + h / 2, y0 + h / 2 * k1)
    k3 = f(t0 + h / 2, y0 + h / 2 * k2)
    k4 = f(t0 + h, y0 + h * k3)
    return y0 + h * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6

y0 = np.array([-9.0656779992979474E+05, -4.8397431127596954E+06, -5.0408120071376814E+06, -7.6805804020022015E+02, 5.4710987127502622E+03, -5.1022193482389539E+03])

N = 1000
h = (tN - t0) / N

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for i in range(N):
    t = t0 + h
    y = rk4(f, h, y0, t0)
#    ax.scatter(y[0], y[1], y[2], c='k', s=2)
    t0 = t
    y0 = y

#plt.show()

print(y[0])
```

Comment: Please check if I rewrote your ODEs correctly.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is the question? Any numerical algorithm will produce small errors which become large on longer intervals. Numerics is never exact. Do you think there is a mistake in your code? Or are you looking for a different algorithm? These would be two very different questions.

Comment: I have to solve the ODE and get exact solution. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Probably there is a problem in my code. I used different methods, all them gave same result. Which is not exactly correct (for 1000km it gave error 100km!)

Comment: @Simon that's not entirely true. Unless the method is unconditionally unstable, you can always perform a stability analysis and find integration steps that keep approximation errors bounded.

Comment: @Kaster Is this method unstable? how to do stability analysis?
The step size is changed in my code comparing the error with 1E-11

Comment: The same results I have using runge-kutta-fehlberg method

Comment: I used it as written here http://maths.cnam.fr/IMG/pdf/RungeKuttaFehlbergProof.pdf

Comment: How do you know your numerical solution is incorrect?

Comment: I don't know if it happened when you were copying your code here, but error analysis and integration step adjustment part got out of the loop.

Comment: Yes. I can't edit it)

Comment: Also I should mention that the interval is very high (in this example I wrote [0,100]), in fact it's [0,21600]. That's why I see the errors

Comment: @Kaster Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Probably something's wrong with your code. Didn't wanna go into it. That's what I got with the time interval [0, 100], 1000 subdivisions and initial conditions [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]. http://imgur.com/a/XfaNe

Comment: If you want to help me, you have to go into it, because my equation is much bigger than the one I wrote here, a lot of constants, etc. I wanted you to check my method, not to solve the ODE :)

Comment: Couple of notes: your problem is not really suited for this SE. not sure where exactly it fits best, maybe stack overflow. Second, your code's not the cleanest one. I understand that coding might not be your primary expertise, so that's fine, but that makes me more reluctant in digging into it. Third, seems like the method you used is not RK4 as you state in the title, but rather 6 step RK. Here's the example of simple but general implementation of RK4 for your prolem (not the much bigger with a lot of constants) that you can easily adapt to probably any equation https://pastebin.com/iiaU5b2x

Comment: In RK4 there is no error correction and step adaptation

Comment: @Kaster I used your code for my equation, it gave the same result as mine. Which is incorrect. Look: https://pastebin.com/DYKJG8z4

Comment: @Kaster The result of program is 1105338.07658, but should be 1092060

Comment: The problem you actually have is very stiff. I'd try to find a way to nondimensionalize it, so all the important variables take values close to 1. It is a usual trick in numerical analysis. As for the time, since none of the RHS functions depend on it, do a translation before scaling

Comment: @Kaster I wrote a new code:https://pastebin.com/tWA7N8h7 Error is smaller, I get 1105326.85644 (correct is 1092060.1)

Comment: @Kaster dopri and other methods also give same error!

Comment: @Kaster The error is smaller, but I can't minimize it more. Would appreciate for your help

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the last section of the accepted answer at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26620/small-errors-accumulate-while-solving-ode-of-motion, the actual error is not numerical, but an omission in transcribing the ODE system. The acceleration of the $z$ component has a slightly different correction factor than the $x$ and $y$ components, see the (transcribed with glitches) documentation for [GLONASS orbit calculations](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia//index.php/GLONASS_Satellite_Coordinates_Computation).

To demonstrate that this was really the only error, independent of the integration method, correct the system to

```
def f(t, y):
    r = (y[0]**2 + y[1]**2 + y[2]**2)**0.5
    r2=r**2
    r3=r**3

    w  = 1+1.5*J2*(req*req/r2)*(1-5*y[2]*y[2]/r2)
    w2 = 1+1.5*J2*(req*req/r2)*(3-5*y[2]*y[2]/r2) # note the 3 here

    return np.array([
        y[3],
        y[4],
        y[5],
        -myu*y[0]*w /r3,
        -myu*y[1]*w /r3,
        -myu*y[2]*w2/r3,
    ])
```

and leave the remaining code for the RK4 integration unchanged. This immediately gives the vector at the end of the integration interval for `N=1000` steps as

```
['1092060.0210', '-1971932.7224', '6685288.7526', '-408.3387', '-7208.3118', '-2057.9943']
```

Increasing the step number by a factor of 4 to `N=4000` gives the result

```
['1092060.1195', '-1971931.2089', '6685289.2632', '-408.3384', '-7208.3122', '-2057.9927']
```

and with `N=10000` steps

```
['1092060.1198', '-1971931.2044', '6685289.2646', '-408.3384', '-7208.3122', '-2057.9927']
```

---

This compares to what you in the comments indicated the result should be:

```
[1092060.1198177, -1971931.204341, 6685289.264684,  -408.338412, -7208.312193, -2057.992705]
```